# Find the top 5 closest rather than just the closest?

Tags: text-processing

How would you find 5 numbers in a column of numbers that are the closest to a `$VariableNumber`?

For example, if the `$VariableNumber` = 30 then:
Example input file:

```
50
100
70
40
20
10
65
41
92
```

Example output:

```
20
40
41
10
50
```

there's an answer that someone’s posted elsewhere before that finds the closest number match in a specific column on a specific line to a given value, which goes as follows:

```
awk -v col_num="3" -v value="$Number" '
    func abs(x) { return (x<0) ? -x : x }

    {
        distance = abs($col_num - value)
    }
    NR==1 || distance<shortest_distance {
        shortest_distance = distance
        nearest_value = $col_num
    }
    END {
        print nearest_value
    }
'
```

But I haven't been able to adapt it

Comment: What have you already tried? Are there any restrictions on the tools you're supposed or willing to use? Independently of the tools, the general approach is to add a "column" containing the absolute value of the difference between each value and $VariableNumber, then sort by that column, cut the column out again, and finally take the first n numbers. You can write this in any language you're comfortable with, including bash + standard Unix commands or any old scripting language.

Comment: I improved the formatting of the script, but I also noticed that the original (and new) produce no output. Test code: `echo -e "1\n4\n19\n35\n" | awk -v c=3 -v t=20 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END {print v}'`

Comment: @richard: Take a closer look at the script: `c=3`, and then all the references to `$c` — as written, this script is finding the number ***in the third column*** that comes closest to 20.  Your `echo` command produces a single column of data, so there is no third column.

Comment: I have re-factored the code, so it may be easier to read. (better variable names, and removed repeated code)

Comment: sorry i lost internet for over a week, going through the answers and comments now, appreciate all the help with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just sort the entries by distance to n and select the first ones like:

```
awk -v n=30 '
  function abs(x) {return x < 0 ? -x : x}
  {print abs($0 - n) "\t" $0}' < file |
  sort -n |
  head -n 5 |
  cut -f 2-
```

Comment: If the data set is very large, then it may be better to put the sort head login inside the awk code, with the head and sort intermingled. So that the code only ever has a list of the top 5. (this will reduce memory consumption from O(n) to O(1), and processing time from O(n log(n)) to O(n). **However you should only care about this if the data sets are very big.**

Answer (score 2):

As usual, [Stéphane’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38420539/3960947#38420540) is very good;
simple and straightforward. 
But, if you really *really* want to do it entirely in `awk`,
and you have GNU `awk` (a.k.a. `gawk`), you can do this:

```
awk -v t="$VariableNumber" '
       {
            d = $1 - t
            if (d < 0) d = -d
            e = d "#" $1
            if (NR <= 5) {
                   a[NR] = e
            } else {
                   a[5+1] = e
                   asort(a, a, "@val_num_asc")
                   delete a[5+1]
            }
       }
  END  {
            print "---"
            if (NR <= 5) asort(a, a, "@val_num_asc")
            for (i in a) { gsub(".*#", "", a[i]); print a[i]; }
       }
'
```

For each input value,
this computes `d` as the absolute **d**ifference
between that value and the **t**arget value,
`t` (which is set on the command line to the value of `$VariableNumber`,
which, as per your example, might be 30). 
It then constructs an array **e**ntry, `e`,
consisting of the difference,
concatenated with a `#` and the original number. 
This array entry is then added to the **a**rray `a`.

The first five input values are simply put into array elements 1 through 5.

After that, each number is appended to the array
by being put into element 6.  Then the array is sorted. 
Since the array entries start with the **d**ifference value,
numbers that are close to the **t**arget
(for which the **d**ifference value is low)
are sorted to the beginning of the array,
and numbers that are far from the **t**arget
are sorted to the end of the array. 
(Specify `"@val_num_asc"`
to sort the values as *numbers* rather than strings. 
Without this, differences of `10` and `20` will sort below `3` and `4`.) 
Then the 6th element (the one that is farthest from the target) is deleted.

Finally (upon reaching the END of the data), we

- Check whether the number of records is ≤ 5. 
  If it is, sort the array,
  because it is still in the order of the input data. 
  (Arguably, this step is optional.)
- For each element is the array,
  strip off the difference and the `#`
  by searching for the regular expression `.*#`
  and substituting (`gsub`) nothing. 
  Then print the original value.

Obviously, if you want to look at a column other the first one,
you can change all the occurrences of `$1` in the script. 
(The script you show in your question
demonstrates how to allow the column number to be specified at run time.) 
And, if you want some number other than the closest five,
just change all appearances of `5`. 
(I could have referred to `a[6]` in lines 9 and 11;
I wrote `a[5+1]` to facilitate simple-minded parameterization.)

Answer (score 1):

Another, for all awks (tested with gawk, mawk, Debian's original-awk and Busybox awk):

```
$ awk -v v=30 -v n=5 '               # v is the central value, 
function abs(d) {                    # n is the number of wanted values
    return (d<0?-d:d)                # d is distance, c array index, va value array
}                                    # da distance array, max is greatest of smallest
((d=abs(v-$1))<max) && c==n {        # if we find distance < max of top n smallest
    da[maxc]=d                       # replace max in distance array
    va[maxc]=$1                      # and in value array
    max=0                            # set max to min to find new max distance
    for(ct in da)
        if(da[ct]>max) {             # find the new max in the top n smallest
            max=da[ct]
            maxc=ct
        }
    if(max==0)                       # if max is 0, all are 0s so might as well exit
        exit
    next
}
c<n {                                # we need n first distances
    da[++c]=d                        # fill distance array with them
    va[c]=$1                         # related values to value array
    if(d>max) {                      # look for max 
        max=d
        maxc=c
    }
}
END {                                # in the end or exit
    for(c in va)                     # get all values in value array
        print va[c]                  # and output them
}' file
```

Output (in no particular order, array implementation related):

```
50
10
41
40
20
```

Execution time is linear, worst case is size of value array times record count so still linear (right? :).